# Link is not functioning with an icon react native but does work with text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am using expo and react native. I am just in the process of setting up rooting, but there is an issue when using icons.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Link } from 'react-router-native'

const Action = ({name, color, size, type}) => {
  return (
    <Link to="/">
      <TouchableHighlight>
        <FontAwesome name={name} size={size} color={color}/>
       </TouchableHighlight>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

If I change it to the following and use `Text` it does work, any ideas why, or how to use `Link` with an icon?

```
  return (
    <Link to="/">
      <Text>Go Home</Text>
    </Link>
  )
```

Comment: tried w/o the TouchableHighlight?

Comment: @Eran it works - oh man, last half hour wasted here :-(

Comment: cool , TouchableHighlight is not needed since the Link component handles the interaction